# Sharepoint Central Administration works, but all other sites are inaccessible

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have installed a standalone Sharepoint Enterprise 2019 server and a Developer SQL 2019 server. I was able to open central administration, create a web application and a site collection. However, when I follow the site collection URL, I instantly get HTTP 404 or 400 errors.

I have tried everything I could think of: recreate the web application and site collection, change ports, use the IP address directly instead of the URL, check that the site is not locked, try to access it from a different computer (still 400 or 404 errors), restart IIS, check that all IIS sites and application pools are running...

Can I get some help here please?

**Update:** I have realized that the sites don't work only when I create URL names of the form "intranet.site.com", even though the DNS is set up. When I create site collections with the URL being the server name, everything works for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that you have configured alternate access mappings for the site collection in the central administration. And you add a new host name in DNS.

You should add IIS binding for the new host.

Go to IIS -> Select the web application from the "Connections" panel on the left under "Sites" node -> Click "Bindings" on the right -> Add -> Enter host name value.

Reference:

[Configure Alternate Access Mapping In SharePoint Server](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Comment: Hi. Thnks for your response. I have created a web app and a site collections with the URL of the form <servername>:<port>, and it works fine. But when I edit bindings in IIS and configure AAM in CA to switch to proper URL like portal.company.com, the site stops working, and I cannot even access it by using the IP address directly.

Comment: I have tried to use the URL of the form portal.company.com.domain.local, and it also works. But I can't get to work the URL that I need: portal.company.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing these sites from the server itself?  If so, you’re running into loopback protection.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/accessing-server-locally-with-fqdn-cname-alias-denied for details.  Although it’s talking about Windows Server 2003, it still applies to more recent server versions.

Comment: I have tried to access it from the server itself, and another machine too. Again, domain url works, but normal url doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a DNS related issue. Could you please check if `nslookup portal.company.com` gives you the desired IP-Address of your server? My following answers will rely on that.